# How to use the androidannotations library in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have tried many time using android annotations library in activity with @EActivity. but unfortunately i am failed to declare it in the manifest file with MainActivity_.

```
@EActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){}
```

in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity_">
```

in this .MainActivity_ not found .

Comment: Welcome to  [so]. Please provide an [mcve] for people to help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read guidelines before posting a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-.

Comment: @chandil03 please can you explain me how can i give you minimal and complete example of this...

Comment: Just read guidelines you will know.

Comment: now its ok or you need more details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably need to enable `kapt` (Kotlin Annotation Processing) in your project.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    kapt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
}
```

Please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html for reference and https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/tree/master/examples/kotlin for an example.

Answer (score 0):

And also you have to declare annotated class as `open` , cause by default all classes in Kotlin are `final`